# Java - Swing Layout + AWT - How to draw a line in a JPanel that was positioned with layouts?

Tags: java, layout, graphics, command-prompt, notepad

For the purpose of another program I need to draw a few lines on the screen which has a image built with incremental painting and layouts. Since the lines were very straight forward and just a few, I thought using the JPanel's painting space to do this. Since this was not working, I made an testing program to try to make it work, but I still can't seem to figure out why this isn't working.

Here is my testing program:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Dimension;


class TestMain{
public static void main(String[]args){
    TestingComponent tester = new TestingComponent();
}
}
class Block extends JPanel{
Block(){
        setOpaque(true);
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics gr){
    super.paintComponent(gr);
    if(getBackground() == Color.white){
        System.out.println("Reached");
        gr.drawLine(getX(), getY(), getX() + getWidth(), getY() + getHeight());
    }
}
}
class TestingComponent{
TestingComponent(){
    JFrame frmMain = new JFrame("testing");
    frmMain.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    JPanel pnlMain = new JPanel();
    Block block = new Block();
    Dimension dmsDim = new Dimension(16, 16);
    pnlMain.setPreferredSize(dmsDim);
    frmMain.add(pnlMain);
    pnlMain.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    for(int index = 0; index < 4; index++){
        block = new Block();
        switch(index){
            case 0:
                block.setBackground(Color.black);
                break;
            case 1:
                block.setBackground(Color.blue);
                break;
            case 2:
                block.setBackground(Color.green);
                break;
            case 3:
                block.setBackground(Color.white);
                break;
        }
        pnlMain.add(block);
    }
    frmMain.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Versions/Programs I'm using (in the testing program) -

Java 8

Notepad

Command Prompt

Seeing how simple the drawLine method is, I'm almost certain it is due to the layouts, but other than that one point, I haven't a clue why the line isn't drawing. The System.out.println("Reached"); is being out-putted, so the program definitely reachs the gr.drawLine().

To clearly state the question... Why isn't the line being drawn? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the wrong points to draw your line

`getX()` and `getY()` return the location of your Component (`Block`) on the parent component.

and because you divide your drawings into two pieces, `getX()` returns the very right coordinate of your panel, `getY()` returns the very upper coordinate.

use `gr.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());` to draw the lines